# How to shut down a second UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, excel

I need to be able to start up a window on a second UI thread and shut it down again at will.

This is my current code:

```
/// <summary>Show or hide the simulation status window on its own thread.</summary>
private void toggleSimulationStatusWindow(bool show)
{
    if (show)
    {
        if (statusMonitorThread != null) return;
        statusMonitorThread = new System.Threading.Thread(delegate()
        {
            Application.Run(new AnalysisStatusWindow(ExcelApi.analyisStatusMonitor));
        });
        statusMonitorThread.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        if (statusMonitorThread != null) 
            statusMonitorThread.Abort();
        statusMonitorThread = null;
    }
}
```

`AnalysisStatusWindow` is a fairly basic `System.Windows.Forms.Form`

The above code is successfully creating the new UI thread, but my request to `Abort` the thread is ignored. The result is that toggling the above function multiple times simply results in new windows opening up - all of which are on their own thread and fully functional.

Is there any way I can pass a message to this thread to shut down nicely? Failing that, is there any way to make sure `Abort()` really kills my second UI thread?

---

I've tried using `new Form().Show()` and `.ShowDialog()` instead of `Application.Run(new Form())`, but they aren't any easier to shut down.

If anyone is questioning the need for a separate UI thread, this code exists in an Excel Add-in, and I cannot control the fact that the Excel UI blocks while calculations for a given cell are underway. For that reason, when a long running custom formula executes, I require this second UI thread to display progress updates.

Comment: You'll need to expose that form instance so you can call its BeginInvoke() method.  To call a public method on the form class that just calls this.Close();

Comment: Thanks buddy, that's the idea I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Hans for his comment. I solved my problem using the following code:

```
/// <summary>Show or hide the simulation status window on its own thread.</summary>
private void toggleSimulationStatusWindow(bool show)
{
    if (show)
    {
        if (statusMonitorThread != null) return;
        statusMonitorWindow = new AnalysisStatusWindow(ExcelApi.analyisStatusMonitor);
        statusMonitorThread = new System.Threading.Thread(delegate()
        {
            Application.Run(statusMonitorWindow);
        });
        statusMonitorThread.Start();
    }
    else if (statusMonitorThread != null)
    {
        statusMonitorWindow.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { statusMonitorWindow.Close(); });
        statusMonitorThread.Join();
        statusMonitorThread = null;
        statusMonitorWindow = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `BeginInvoke` can be simplified to `statusMonitorWindow.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)statusMonitorWindow.Close);` as `Close()` satisfies the `MethodInvoker` signature.